# Issue in obtaining json data from the URL in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, web-services

Hi all am Working on web service for mobile applications in my case the data from the mobile will be received in the json format the problem is i can't  decode the json data only i can get the post values of it

json data send from mobile

```
test:{"username":"abc1234","emailid":"abc@asd.com","password":"abc123","transactionpassword":"abc1234","phone":"1234567890","secretquestion":"What is the name of my pet?","secretanswer":"Tom"}
```

the following array obtained by

```
print_r($_POST);
    Array
    (
        [------WebKitFormBoundaryXb9aAj9gBd1dA41z
    Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => "test"

    {"username":"abc1234","emailid":"abc@asd.com","password":"abc123","transactionpassword":"abc1234","phone":"1234567890","secretquestion":"What is the name of my pet?","secretanswer":"Tom"}
    ------WebKitFormBoundaryXb9aAj9gBd1dA41z--

    )
```

while i tried to decode it no results were shown

```
print_r(json_decode($_POST));
```

empty

Help me to decode the json data in php

Comment: print_r(json_decode($_POST,true)); some changes pass json_decode(param,param) two paramenter.please add and try

Comment: The second parameter just returns an associative array. The value is empty because the json_decode fails.

Comment: print_r(json_decode($_POST,true)); It shows empty results @pawansen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you should fetch actual POST param first.

`json_decode($_POST['test'])`